# SQL Query for start date & end date range between record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have database structured like this:

[image]

and Output like this:

[image]

so, how to make SQL Query?

Comment: Don't link images, show us text.  Also, I'm pretty sure this question has been answered already on Stack Overflow.  Did you search before posting your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

first we need to generate `CalendarData` on the fly using `sys.all_objects` or `[master]..spt_values` as shown here:

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '2017-01-01',
        @MaxDate DATE = '2017-12-31';

SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
    DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate) as CalendarDate
FROM
    sys.all_objects a
CROSS JOIN 
    sys.all_objects b;
```

For more information check this link https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2

So the full solution might be like

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '2017-01-01',
        @MaxDate DATE = '2017-12-31';

WITH calendareDates AS
(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.number) - 1, @MinDate) AS CalendarDate
    FROM    
        [master]..spt_values a
    --CROSS JOIN [master]..spt_values b   -- use this cross join to get more records only if your dates between Start and End Date are over years.
)
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CalendarDate) id,
    c.CalendarDate, e.eventTitle, e.eventId  
FROM
    Events e 
LEFT JOIN
    calendareDates c ON c.CalendarDate BETWEEN e.StartDate AND e.EndDate
```